# How to search the part of a text using tsv c#?

Tags: c#, csv, entity-framework-core, postgresql-12, tsvector

I am using the tsv column in the table. In C#, in the LINQ query, I am searching the text like below

```
var result = (from student in context.Students
              where student.Tsv.Matches(EF.Functions.PlainToTsQuery(searchText))
              select student.name).ToList();
```

For example, we have one sentence like "Start to write. Pasting the text or something".

If search full sentence or full word means, it is working.

But If search part of the word means, it is not working.

Eg: In the above sentence, search like `past`, `some` means, it is not working.

How to achieve it?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Ankit, I added the LINQ Query.

Comment: `.Contain(txtSearch.Text)` solve your probrm.

Comment: @NEBEZ, Tsv is a tsvector column. NpgsqlTsVector does not have "Contains".

Comment: I think it would be ideal if you can also share the table schema.